# Unknown column 'Moto G 3rd Generation' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

Probably just a minor mistake, but I am getting above message when I try to query this string.

```
INSERT INTO `data`(`title`, `category`, `price`, `link`) VALUES (`Moto G 3rd Generation`,`mobiles`,`8999`,`https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=godaddy%20mysql&es_th=1`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape string values with quotos and column and table names with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `data`(`title`, `category`, `price`, `link`) 
VALUES ('Moto G 3rd Generation', ...
```

Comment: @krzyk: Please don't ask people to accept answers. That is their decision. Even more for people that accepted answers in the past and know how it works.

Comment: I could not mark it as accepted because you can only accept after 15 min and it was showing error.